# blob_send save_as=True fails after converting from db to ndb

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

I converted [nicks blog](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/03/Implementing-a-dropbox-service-with-the-Blobstore-API-Part-1) example to ndb
now this line fails:

```
self.send_blob(file_info.blob, save_as=True)
```

with this error:

```
ValueError: Expected BlobInfo value for blob_key_or_info.
```

Rest of the class:

```
class FileDownloadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
   def get(self, file_id):
       file_info = models.FileInfo.get_by_id(long(file_id))

if not file_info or not file_info.blob:
  self.error(404)
  return

self.send_blob(file_info.blob)
#self.send_blob(file_info.blob, save_as=True)
```

Why did the result change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NDB you have to use a ndb.BlobKeyProperty() to hold the blobkey.

To use it :

```
class FileInfo(ndb.Model):     
    ....
    blob_ref = ndb.BlobKeyProperty() 
....

file_info = models.FileInfo.get_by_id(... key_name ....)
self.send_blob(blobstore.BlobInfo.get(file_info.blob_ref), save_as=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, I just needed to change the send_blob (I had already converted the blob reference to ndb)  self.send_blob(blobstore.BlobInfo.get(file_info.blob), save_as=True)